# Why Use Properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, properties

So I've been programming on Objective-C for over a year now, and I can't seem to understand the use for properties.  I have searched the internet a few times but never really found a good explaniation.  I understand how to create them:

```
@property (something, something) something *variableName;
@syntheize variableName;
```

But should I make all my instance variables properties.  To me, from what I know, it seems like a waste of code.  But when I look at code online, sometimes I see like 25 properties in one class.  Which I think is a waste.  The only time I ever use them is when passing info from a `UITableView` cell selected to a detail `viewController`.  For that, I use:

```
@property (copy) NSString *myString;
```

Can you also explain what: `nonatomic`, `copy`, `retain`, `assign`, etc. mean.

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Answer (score 7):

These properties are convenience methods for creating getters and setters.

---

**Atmoic v Nonatomic**

Assuming that you are `@synthesizing` the method implementations, atomic vs. non-atomic changes the generated code. If you are writing your own setter/getters, atomic/nonatomic/retain/assign/copy are merely advisory.

With atomic, the synthesized setter/getter will ensure that a whole value is always returned from the getter or set by the setter, regardless of setter activity on any other thread. That is, if thread A is in the middle of the getter while thread B calls the setter, an actual viable value -- an autoreleased object, most likely -- will be returned to the caller in A.

In nonatomic, no such guarantees are made. Thus, nonatomic is considerably faster than atomic.

What atomic does not do is make any guarantees about thread safety. If thread A is calling the getter simultaneously with thread B and C calling the setter with different values, thread A may get any one of the three values returned -- the one prior to any setters being called or either of the values passed into the setters in B and C. Likewise, the object may end up with the value from B or C, no way to tell.

Ensuring data integrity -- one of the primary challenges of multi-threaded programming -- is achieved by other means.

---

**Assign, retain, copy**

In a nutshell, assign vs retain vs copy determines how the synthesized accessors interact with the Objective-C memory management scheme:

- assign is the default and simply performs a variable assignment
- retain specifies the new value should be sent -retain on assignment and the old value sent release
- copy specifies the new value should be sent -copy on assignment and the old value sent release.

Remember that retain is done on the created object (it increases the reference count) whereas copy creates a new object. The difference, then, is whether you want to add another retain to the object or create an entirely new object.

Answer (score 3):

Properties are a good technique to expose values. You shouldn't expose all instance variables as that would break good OOP encapsulation.

Here is Apple's documentation on the matter.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

A key point is:

> Declared properties address the problems with standard accessor
>   methods by providing the following features:
>
> - The property declaration provides a clear, explicit specification of
>     how the accessor methods behave.
> - The compiler can synthesize accessor methods for you, according to
>     the specification you provide in the declaration. This means you have
>     less code to write and maintain.
> - Properties are represented syntactically as identifiers and are
>     scoped, so the compiler can detect use of undeclared properties.

Answer (score 0):

Properties enable automatic handling of the variables.  So when you do a synthesize the compiler will generate your getters and setters allowing one to do class.variableName = value (indicating that the compiler will execute [class variableName:value].

Pretty decent explanation of the properties here: http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Answer (score 0):

The properties is a nice feature which gives you getter and setter method automatically by synthesize and give you relief by not setting and getting the value.

A property may be declared as "readonly", and may be provided with storage semantics such as "assign", "copy" or "retain". By default, properties are considered atomic, which results in a lock preventing multiple threads from accessing them at the same time. A property can be declared as "nonatomic", which removes this lock (reference from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

If you need getters and setters to expose some instance variables, or you want some automatic retain/release memory management or thread safe accessors, then properties are a less verbose way to automatically create these smart getters and setters.  If you don't want to expose something outside an object or thread, and don't want runtime memory management (say, for some malloc'd C struct) then properties might either a waste, or syntactic sugar (which may or may not improve code readability), or put there by a coder who doesn't know the difference.